# increment plist value

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I'm trying to increment a value in a plist in objective-c (using cocos2d).

I'm loading data using this:

```
documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* filePath2 = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"weaponchallenges.plist"];
    weaponChallengesList = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath2] retain];
```

I believe this works as it is not erroring, although I'm not sure the best way to test this.

Inside the plist are various Dictionary items, within each items various keys + integers.

For example the first item in the plist has an item key 'kills' with an int value of 0.

I'm then using:

```
NSDictionary * weaponC = [weaponChallengesList objectAtIndex:0];
        int killsTotal = [[weaponC valueForKey:@"kills"] intValue];
        [weaponC setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(killsTotal + 1)] forKey:@"kills"];
        [weaponChallengesList replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:weaponC];
```

But killsTotal always seems to be 0, any thoughts on what I could be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check each step to see if the value is `nil`. Routines like `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` do not generate errors. They just return `nil`. So you'll wind up with `weaponChallengesList` is `nil`, `weaponC` is `nil`, `killsTotal` is 0, and your `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` silently doing nothing.

In ObjC, if "nothing" seems to happen, then the #1 cause is that you're messaging `nil`.

Comment: thanks, it seems weaponChallengesList is indeed nil. Not sure why are I'm loading data from another plist in an identical way..

Comment: Ok resolved it! The problem was, with the plist I was using.. <dict><dict>, rather than <array><dict>, so it was just returning an empty array, rather than being just nil.